# Bounding Above an $o(x)$ Function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

If we have some function $f(x)$ that is real, strictly monotone increasing, and is $o(x)$, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$, does this mean that we can find some polynomial $x^d$ with $0<d<1$ bounding $f$ from above?

I've tried thinking about this in terms of an asymptotic expansion of $f$ using different asymptotic scales but not made much progress.

If not, are there any further restrictions that would guarantee this?

Comment: You can bound it on an interval $[a,+\infty)$.  But not everywhere.

Comment: A polynomial has positive integer exponents. $x^{1/2}$ for example is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question, as I understand it, is whether there is any sublinear function that grows faster than sublinear polynomials. The answer is yes.

Take $f(x)=\frac{x}{\log x}$. Then $f(x)\in o(x)$ because $\frac{1}{\log x}\to 0$ (as $x\to \infty$), but $f(x)$ grows faster than any $x^d,0<d<1$ because:

$$ x^d=\frac{x}{x^{1-d}}$$

and powers grow faster than logarithms i.e. $x^{1-d}\in \Omega(\log x)$ so $\frac{x}{x^{1-d}}\in o\left(\frac{x}{\log x}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you that! This counter example is exactly what I was looking for!